# Exe files not available in java jar dependency

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, selenium-chromedriver

I have project A and project B.
Project A is test automation framework , project B is functional-test project.

Have added /drivers directory with chromedriver.exe to project A, have built an artifact in Jenkins and updated it's dependency in project B where snapshot has been successfully imported but in .jar I don't see /drivers directory.

I've tried to clean, compile, install, force remove external libs and importing again but it didn't help.

[image: ProjectA]
[image: ProjectB]

What could cause issue ?

I am not sure if it's mvn fault,  cause maybe jar do not accept exe file inside ?

Comment: You can put any file in a jar, it's just a zip file. But you should note that you cannot run an EXE from a jar. You have to extract it first, then run it.

Comment: exe file in jar? how can you even use that with jar?

Comment: @RealSkeptic
ok, but so far they should be visible anyway even in exe (not zipped) format - rigth ?

Comment: the src/main/java tree is only used for .java files unless you specify explicitly having resources in there. Otherwise, the package should have been in src/main/resources, in which case it will be included in the jar file.

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen   you are rigth  :)  !